# Boxes with angled bottom and top

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to know how can I make in CSS3 angled boxes. Like this site:
http://themeluxe.com/themes/glissando/ (the whites ones)

And how can I make the borders look better, smooth.

Looking on their code, I found this css:

```
.container:before, .container:after {
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    border-left: 110vw solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -80px;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
}
```

But is not working for me.

Comment: Another nice template with angled borders http://parasponsive.com/para4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the website you link to they use the "border technique" to create the oblique boxes on pseudo elements you may understand this technique in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work).

Here is a simple fiddle using this technique to create the oblique bottom and top. It should help you understand how it works :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/F46GV/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div{
    height:200px;
    background:teal;
    position:relative;
}
.second{
    background:gold;
}

.second:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    border-left:100vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid gold;
}
```

You should also be aware that in the website you link to, they are using [`vw` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths). They are [not supported by IE8-](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check the link! Really appreciate it!